# Restarting a Python Program

Tags: python

I know this has been asked before, but I haven't understood the answer.

My code is this:

```
# Code by Jake Stringer
# 2014

import os
print("                       Hailstone Numbers ")
print("")
print("An interesting area of Maths - demonstrated by Jake Stringer")
print("")
input("Please press enter to continue.")

os.system('CLS')

print("Hailstone Numbers:")
print("")
print("RULE 1: Start with any number.")
print("If it is even > divide it by 2.")
print("If it is odd > multiply it by 3, then add 1")
print("")
print("RULE 2: Keep going")
print("")
print("RULE 3: You will always end up at 1.")
print("")
print ("Let's put Hailstone Numbers into action.")
print("")

user = int(input("Please enter any number: "))

print("")

os.system('CLS')


print (user)
print("")

if user % 2 == 0 : 

    print("What you entered is an even number.")
    print("")

    print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now divide it by 2.")

    user = int(user)/2
    thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."

    print (thing2)
else : 

    print("What you entered is an odd number.")
    print("")

    print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now multiply it by 3, and add 1.")

    user = int(user)*3
    user += 1

    thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."
    print (thing2)

input("Please press enter to continue.")
os.system('CLS')

print("According to RULE 2, we need to keep on going.")

while user > 1:
    thing3 = "We are currently on the number " + str(user) + "."
    print (thing3)

    if user % 2 == 0 : 

        print("This number is an even number.")
        print("")

        print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now divide it by 2.")

        user = int(user)/2
        thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."

        print (thing2)
    else : 

        print("This number is an odd number.")
        print("")

        print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now multiply it by 3, and add 1.")

        user = int(user)*3
        user += 1

        thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."
        print (thing2)
    print("Now we will continue.")
    input("Please press the enter key.")
    os.system('CLS')
    print("")

print(user)
print("")
print("As you can see, you have ended up on the number 1.")
print("")
print("                       Hailstone Numbers ")
print("")
print("An interesting area of Maths - demonstrated by Jake Stringer")
print("")
restart = input("Would you like a try the program again??")

if restart == "yes":
    # restart code here!
else:
# quit the program!
```

.... So, how do I make the program restart? I have seen in past answers to use some code that when I tried out, says that "sys" isn't defined (so I'm guessing it doesn't exist). It should also be noted that I'm a beginner at Python. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Did you *import* `sys`? Just like `os`, `sys` is a module, not a built-in.

Comment: Ok, but what code would I then execute to restart the program?

Comment: You didn't show us what answer here on SO you tried.

Comment: also the code at the bottom that has the "else" part gives the error "expected an indented block".

Comment: why restart the program? what you want is to execute these code again if the user input "yes". you simply put the code into a function, say myfunc. at the end of code, if restart == "yes" call myfunc again, else do nothing.

Comment: @gingepusscat123, you have no code in your if restart == "yes": statement, that is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in a loop as follows:

```
# Code by Jake Stringer
# 2014

import os
restart = 'yes'
while restart in ('yes', 'Yes', 'y', 'Y'):
    print("                       Hailstone Numbers ")
    print("")
    print("An interesting area of Maths - demonstrated by Jake Stringer")
    print("")
    input("Please press enter to continue.")

    os.system('CLS')

    print("Hailstone Numbers:")
    print("")
    print("RULE 1: Start with any number.")
    print("If it is even > divide it by 2.")
    print("If it is odd > multiply it by 3, then add 1")
    print("")
    print("RULE 2: Keep going")
    print("")
    print("RULE 3: You will always end up at 1.")
    print("")
    print ("Let's put Hailstone Numbers into action.")
    print("")

    user = int(input("Please enter any number: "))

    print("")

    os.system('CLS')


    print (user)
    print("")

    if user % 2 == 0 : 

        print("What you entered is an even number.")
        print("")

        print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now divide it by 2.")

        user = int(user)/2
        thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."

        print (thing2)
    else : 

        print("What you entered is an odd number.")
        print("")

        print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now multiply it by 3, and add 1.")

        user = int(user)*3
        user += 1

        thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."
        print (thing2)

    input("Please press enter to continue.")
    os.system('CLS')

    print("According to RULE 2, we need to keep on going.")

    while user > 1:
        thing3 = "We are currently on the number " + str(user) + "."
        print (thing3)

        if user % 2 == 0 : 

            print("This number is an even number.")
            print("")

            print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now divide it by 2.")

            user = int(user)/2
            thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."

            print (thing2)
        else : 

            print("This number is an odd number.")
            print("")

            print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now multiply it by 3, and add 1.")

            user = int(user)*3
            user += 1

            thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."
            print (thing2)
        print("Now we will continue.")
        input("Please press the enter key.")
        os.system('CLS')
        print("")

    print(user)
    print("")
    print("As you can see, you have ended up on the number 1.")
    print("")
    print("                       Hailstone Numbers ")
    print("")
    print("An interesting area of Maths - demonstrated by Jake Stringer")
    print("")
    restart = input("Would you like a try the program again??")
```

Answer (score 3):

Stick the whole thing in a function and then put a repeat-loop outside the function.

```
import os

def my_function():
    print("                       Hailstone Numbers ")
    print("")
    # more code here
    print("An interesting area of Maths - demonstrated by Jake Stringer")
    print("")


while True:
    my_function()
    restart = input("Would you like a try the program again??")
    if restart == "yes":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

You might want to head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and get some folks to look over your code, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll make sure to try the Code Review place if I have a problem again.

Comment: @gingepusscat123 code review isn't to solve problems, but if you have working code you can get advice on how to improve it